# Document.write not working

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript function to calculate total amount :

```
<script>
function calculate(v)
{

    v = parseFloat(v);
    v = v + 19;
    //alert(v);
    document.write.getElementById("total") = v;

}

</script>
```

which is within `<head></head>` section . I am calling this function from :

```
Select amount you want to buy : <input type="text" name="qty"  onkeyup="calculate(this.value)"/> grams
```

And I am trying to display value of `v` here :

```
<div id="total"><script> document.write(v);</script></div>
```

But it is not showing anything. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.write.getElementById("total") = v;
```

This is not how `document.write` works and will throw an error in the JavaScript console. Always make sure you check the console for possible errors first.

You are looking for [`.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM%3aelement.innerHTML).

Answer (score 4):

`document.write` only works on an "open" document.  When the end of the file is reached, the document is closed for writing (at least through those outdated means).  I believe most browsers will just ignore an attempt to write to a closed document, but some may throw an error.

Other issues at hand here are that you are not calling `document.write()` but trying to access yet another field (or child) of that function, `getElementById`, which doesn't exist.

Finally, in your last bit of code, you are attempting to write the value of `v` which is a local variable to the `calculate()` function so it doesn't really exist outside that scope.

A few other people have already pointed out remedies to this, namely `document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = <your value>`.  Accessing `innerHTML` is not the cleanest way to do things, but it works in all major browsers and is easy to understand.

Hope that a little bit of explanation about what was going is helpful.  Good luck!  (Think about learning one of the many javascript frameworks if you get much further into it -- they can be a great help.  Prototype.js, jQuery, Dojo, MooTools, etc., are all good.)

Answer (score 3):

You have a misunderstanding of how `document.write()` works.

You *probably* want...

```
var elem = document.getElementById("total");

if (elem.textContent) {
   elem.textContent = v;
} else {
   elem.innerText = v;
}
```

Comment: But the element in question is a `div`?

Answer (score 1):

```
//document.write.getElementById("total") = v;
document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = v;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
you can do this

 document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = v;

 document.write(v);
```

Answer (score 0):

: incorrect `document.write.getElementById("total") = v;`

`document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = v;`